# delete in inherited class causes symbol lookup error

Tags: c++, dll

## Issue:

I've been trying to create an inherited class (in a DLL, but that's not necessarily relevant). I get a symbol lookup error, though (an unresolved external).

## Code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
    virtual ~Foo() = 0;
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    Bar() { std::cout << "Bar()\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Bar->print\n"; }
    virtual ~Bar() { std::cout << "~Bar()\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Foo *b = new Bar();
    b->print();
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

Upon compiling, I get the following error:

**bla.cpp:(.text._ZN3BarC2Ev[_ZN3BarC5Ev]+0x47): undefined reference to `Foo::~Foo()**

## SOLUTION:

The issue is that you can't have a pure virtual destructor (still not clear as to why that is). So changing this:

```
virtual ~Foo() = 0;
```

to this:

```
virtual ~Foo() {}
```

Fixes everything. Thanks to the user, me', for the solution

Comment: @drescherjm At first I didn't want to add too much text to make the post difficult to read. I formatted it to include the question and the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing virtual ~LibBase() = 0; to virtual  ~LibBase(){} works on Window(MinGW) with the output:

> Lib
>
> Print
>
> ~Lib
>
> Leaving Main

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually noticed it just before you submitted this, upon looking more into virtual destructors. But why must the virtual destructor be defined? To make matters worse, if it's still pure (~LibBase() = 0;) and there exists a declaration (LibBase::~LibBase() {}), it still works fine! Is there a reason for this?